# Autodesk Forge Viewer API not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, autodesk-forge

A few days ago, I was trying to build Autodesk forge viewer API with react native by following this example:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-react-native-au-talk

It works well. It used viewer v2.17, I up to viewer v7 but unfortunately, It doesn't show anything. I caught an error: Cannot read property 'texture' of null, when I use line viewer.start();

Please, help

Comment: How did you initialize the viewer after upgrading to v7 (post your code, the code [here](https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/1f53cc86cab2f5de1bc2eaa364503168#file-styles-js-L44) no longer works for v7)? Did you follow [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/starting-html/)? Did you code work in a plain old browser?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems to me you're not using the viewer options properly on initializing.
The way to define the access token is by a callback as per the sample posted by Bryan.
Using the code below the viewer loaded in fine.

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/style.min.css?v=v7.*" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.min.js?v=v2.17"></script>
  <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=v7.*"></script>
</head>

<body style="margin:0">
  <div id="viewer"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var viewer = null;
  function initializeViewer(urn, token) {
    var options = {
      env: "AutodeskProduction",
      getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
        var token = 'access token provided by 2 legged api';
        var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
        onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
      }
    }
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, () => {
      try {
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('viewer'));
        viewer.start();
        console.log('viewer loaded');
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err)
      }
    });

    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
      var viewables = doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
      viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables).then(i => {
        // documented loaded, any action?
      });
    }

    function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
      console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
    }
  }
</script>
```